# Having a trouble avoiding the wall

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I tried quite alot of ways and for some reasons the snake in the code is not able to avoid the walls at all. The red dot is a snake whole the green dot is a food. In the maze, empty white space is 0 and -1 is denoted by the wall. Below is my code for Searching Agent:

```
import heapq

class A_Star_Implementation:
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state
        self.maze = state.maze.MAP
        self.start = (state.snake.HeadPosition.X, state.snake.HeadPosition.Y)
        self.goal = (state.FoodPosition.X, state.FoodPosition.Y)

    def heuristic(self, a, b):
        # Use Manhattan distance as the heuristic
        return abs(a[0] - b[0]) + abs(a[1] - b[1])

    def a_star_search(self):
        open_set = []
        heapq.heappush(open_set, (0 + self.heuristic(self.start, self.goal), 0, self.start))
        came_from = {}
        g_score = {self.start: 0}

        while open_set:
            _, _, current = heapq.heappop(open_set)
            
            if current == self.goal:
                return self.reconstruct_path(came_from, current)
            
            for dx, dy in [(1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)]:  # Directions: right, down, left, up
                neighbor = (current[0] + dx, current[1] + dy)
                if 0 <= neighbor[0] < len(self.maze) and 0 <= neighbor[1] < len(self.maze[0]):
                    if self.maze[neighbor[0]][neighbor[1]] == -1:  # Skip walls
                        continue
                    tentative_g_score = g_score[current] + 1
                    
                    if neighbor not in g_score or tentative_g_score < g_score.get(neighbor, float('inf')):
                        came_from[neighbor] = current
                        g_score[neighbor] = tentative_g_score
                        f_score = tentative_g_score + self.heuristic(neighbor, self.goal)
                        heapq.heappush(open_set, (f_score, tentative_g_score, neighbor))
        return []

    def reconstruct_path(self, came_from, current):
        path = []
        while current in came_from:
            path.append(current)
            current = came_from[current]
        path.append(self.start)  # optional
        path.reverse()  # optional
        return path

    def convert_path_to_plan(self, path):
        plan = []
        for i in range(1, len(path)):
            current, next = path[i - 1], path[i]
            if next[0] == current[0] + 1:
                plan.append(3)  # Right
            elif next[0] == current[0] - 1:
                plan.append(9)  # Left
            elif next[1] == current[1] + 1:
                plan.append(6)  # Down
            elif next[1] == current[1] - 1:
                plan.append(0)  # Up
        return plan

    def SearchSolution(self):
        print("Searching for Solution using A*")
        path = self.a_star_search()
        return self.convert_path_to_plan(path)

class Agent(object):
    def SearchSolution(self, state):
        return []
        
class AgentSnake(Agent):    
    def SearchSolution(self, state):
        print("AgentSnake searching for solution...")
        a_star_solver = A_Star_Implementation(state)
        plan = a_star_solver.SearchSolution()
        return plan
    def showAgent():
        print("A Snake Solver By MB")
```

and the state code is as following:

```
import random

class Const:
    UNIT_SIZE = 10

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
    def show(self):
        print("[" , self.X, ", ", self.Y, "]")
    
    def Update(self, X, Y):
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        
    def Add(self, Vec):
        self.X = self.X + Vec.X
        self.Y = self.Y + Vec.Y

class Maze:
    def __init__(self, PuzzleFileName):
        self.MAP = []
        self.LoadMaze(PuzzleFileName)
    def LoadMaze(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            line = f.readline()
            [self.HEIGHT, self.WIDTH] = [int(digit) for digit in line.split()]
            self.MAP = [[int(digit) for digit in line.split()] for line in f]

class Snake:
    def __init__(self, Color, HeadPositionX = 10, HeadPositionY = 10, HeadDirectionX = 1, HeadDirectionY = 0):
        self.Size = 1
        self.Body = [] #in this implementation the body is empty
        self.Color = Color
        self.HeadPosition = Vector(HeadPositionX, HeadPositionY)
        self.HeadDirection = Vector(HeadDirectionX, HeadDirectionY)
        self.score = 0
        self.isAlive = True
    
    def moveSnake(self, State):
        
        if(self.isAlive == False):
            return

        self.HeadPosition.Add(self.HeadDirection)

        r = self.HeadPosition.Y
        c = self.HeadPosition.X
        
        if(r >= State.maze.HEIGHT or r < 0) or (c >= State.maze.WIDTH or c < 0):
            self.isAlive = False
        elif(State.maze.MAP[r][c] == -1):
            self.isAlive = False
        elif(c == State.FoodPosition.X and r == State.FoodPosition.Y):
            self.score = self.score + 10
                
class SnakeState():
    def __init__(self, Color, HeadPositionX, HeadPositionY, HeadDirectionX, HeadDirectionY, mazeFileName):
        self.snake = Snake(Color, HeadPositionX, HeadPositionY, HeadDirectionX, HeadDirectionY)
        self.maze = Maze(mazeFileName)
        self.generateFood()
    
    def generateFood(self):
        """
        Method to randomly place a circular 'food' object anywhere on Canvas.
        The tag on it is used for making decisions in the program
        """
        FoodFlag = False
        while (FoodFlag == False):
            x = random.randrange(3, self.maze.WIDTH  - 3)
            y = random.randrange(3, self.maze.HEIGHT - 3)

            if(self.maze.MAP[y][x] != -1):
                FoodFlag = True
                
        self.FoodPosition = Vector(x,y)
    
    def printState(self):
        # Printing the current state of the snake and the maze
        print("Snake Head Position:", end=" ")
        self.snake.HeadPosition.show()
        print("Food Position:", end=" ")
        self.FoodPosition.show()
        # Printing the maze
        print("Maze:")
        for row in self.maze.MAP:
            print(row)
```

and main.py is as

```
import threading
import State as ST
import AgentSnake as AS
import time
import View as V


class Main: 
    def __init__(self, State, AgentSnake, SnakeSpeed=30):
        self.State = State
        self.AgentSnake = AgentSnake
        self.View = V.SnakeViewer(self.State,SnakeSpeed)
        
    def setDirection(self, k):
        if(k == 0):
            self.State.snake.HeadDirection.X = 0
            self.State.snake.HeadDirection.Y = -1
        elif(k == 6):
            self.State.snake.HeadDirection.X = 0
            self.State.snake.HeadDirection.Y = 1
        elif(k == 3):
            self.State.snake.HeadDirection.X = 1
            self.State.snake.HeadDirection.Y = 0
        elif(k == 9):
            self.State.snake.HeadDirection.X = -1
            self.State.snake.HeadDirection.Y = 0    
    
    def ExecutePlan(self, Plan):
        for k in Plan:
            self.setDirection(k)        
            self.State.snake.moveSnake(self.State)
            if(self.State.snake.isAlive == False):
                break
            time.sleep(1/self.View.SPEED)
            self.View.UpdateView()  
    
    def StartSnake(self):
        if(self.State.snake.isAlive == False):
            return
        PlanIsGood = True
        Message = "Game Over"
        while(self.State.snake.isAlive and PlanIsGood):
            ScoreBefore = self.State.snake.score
            
            Plan = self.AgentSnake.SearchSolution(self.State)
            self.ExecutePlan(Plan)
            
            ScoreAfter = self.State.snake.score
            
            if(ScoreAfter == ScoreBefore):
                PlanIsGood = False
            self.State.generateFood()
            time.sleep(1/2)

        if(self.State.snake.isAlive):
            Message = Message + "  HAS A BAD PLAN"
        else:
            Message = Message + " HAS HIT A WALL"
        self.View.ShowGameOverMessage(Message)
    def Play(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.StartSnake)
        t1.start()
        t2 = threading.Thread(target= self.View.top.mainloop()) 
        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()   
            
def main():
    state = ST.SnakeState('red', 10, 10, 0, 1,"Maze.txt")
    Agent = AS.AgentSnake() 
    state.printState()
    Game = Main(state,Agent)
    Game.Play()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Appreciate some advice and mistakes so I can do better in other searching algorithms. Right now I haven't added other algos so really appreciate the help in figuring this problem out [image: The Snake hit by the wall]